# Language Switch only one language link with typoscript

Tags: typo3

I like to create a language switcher with typoscript but i don't want to show two languages, only one language will show, mean when the user is in the french language he will see a link for the german site, and when he is in german he will see the french link, not the regulare FR | DE menu.

Anyone have an idea please ?

Best,

mmasmoudi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the options TYPO3 offers you:
I assume you build the [language menu](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html#special-language) with

```
lib.langMenu = HMENU
lib.langMenu.special = language
```

then you can remove the display of the current language with

```
lib.langMenu.1.ACT.doNotShowLink = 1
```

Comment: Yes extactly , used that typoscript, and i must delete all the TEXT of current lang not only the typolink.

Comment: removing the link only can be done with `doNotLinkIt = 1`, with `doNotShowLink = 1` nothing is shown (from [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/Tmenuitem/Index.html): "_If set, the text will not be shown at all (smart with spacers)._")

Comment: Thanks, yes, this delete the text.